# how to call a php function from a class and return the value in vue js?

Tags: php, vue.js

I'm learning vue but for some reason couldn't find an answer to this simple question. I have a php class called `DataFetcher` and i have a vue file and inside of it i wanna call a method from `DataFetcher` and print the result in the vue page. I've always done it with data passed from props like this (learned it from the tutorials i've watched):

`<form-input name="someName" id="someName" v-model="alien.id"></form-input>`

Now i wanna call the method `getAlienName($alienId)` of the class `DataFetcher` and put the result in the `v-model`. Something like this:

`<form-input name="someName2" id="someName2" v-model="DataFetcher.getAlienName(alien.id)"></form-input>`

How can I achieve this?

`getAlienName($alienId)` is merely a method that has a db query that returns a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call PHP functions from a vue context. PHP is executed on the server side, while vue is executed on the client side.

You will have to define an API of some sort to call the function. Just an example:

**vue**: HTTP GET `localhost/api.php?alienId=1337`

**php**:

```
<?PHP

echo myFunction($_GET['alienId']);
```

Comment: that makes sense, thank you and sorry for not thinking of it

Comment: It's a common beginner mistake, no worries.